# SQL update statement from a history table based on timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to write an `update` statement in Oracle that will find an attribute from a history table based on a timestamp.  So, for example the data looks like:

```
TABLE A
A_ID  TIMESTAMP              ATTR
---------------------------------
1     5/27/2012 10:30:00 AM  ?

TABLE B
B_ID  A_ID  TIMESTAMP              ATTR
---------------------------------------
1     1     5/26/2012 9:01:08 AM   W
2     1     5/27/2012 8:38:21 AM   X
3     1     5/28/2012 9:01:01 AM   Y
4     1     5/29/2012 11:37:54 PM  Z
```

The lower bound is >= B.TIMESTAMP, but I'm not sure how to write the upper bound as < B."the next TIMESTAMP".  So, in the example above the attribute on table A should update to "X".

This seems like a fairly common use case. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803758/sql-update-with-value-from-other-table-depending-on-timestamp), but it looks like a satisfactory answer was never reached, so I thought I'd post again.

Comment: you first have to emit a written clear rule in a sentence, before you actually could start building a query. What is the definition of the candidate record from TABLE B?

Comment: The rule is: find the record in TABLE B where TABLE A's timestamp is >= TABLE B's timestamp, but < TABLE B's next timestamp, unless it is the last timestamp and the FK (A_ID) matches. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE A SET attr = (
    SELECT b1.attr 
    FROM B b1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(b3.timestamp) mx FROM B b3
            WHERE b3.timestamp < A.timestamp
        ) b2 ON b1.timestamp = b2.mx
)
```

I can't remember if Oracle will allow me to use table A within the inner join sub query... Would you mind trying it?

Comment: The join was allowed, but did not pass all my test cases.  I'll play around with it and see if I can find the issue.

Comment: Could you give me more informations please? What went wrong (example please)?

Comment: Not every timestamp on the inner select that should have returned a value did. I have a more complex data set for testing.